# Add class on click at a specific item in a grid in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a grid of items (created in flexbox so as to use v-for loops).
I would like to add class `.selected` on click on a specific item in a list.
There's a problem that item in every column gets class that should be applied only to a single element. What should I do to make it work?

Grid:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: 8,
    items: [
      {
        selected: false
      },
      {
        selected: false
      },
      {
        selected: false
      },
      {
        selected: false
      },
      {
        selected: false
      },
      {
        selected: false
      },
      {
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.app > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  padding-bottom: 4vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.app > ul > li.row > ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
.app > ul > li.row > ul li {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.app > ul > li.row > ul li.selected {
  background-color: gray;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="row in rows" class="row">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item, index in items" :key="index" :class="{ selected: item.selected }" @click="item.selected = !item.selected"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking along the right lines. It's your data structure that's the problem.

You only have 7 items - but you're expecting them to behave like 8 rows of 7 items. Your data object should reflect the structure you are looping in the DOM.

Something like this would be what you are after:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [
      {
        items: [
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        items: [
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        items: [
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        items: [
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        items: [
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        items: [
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        items: [
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        items: [
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          },
          {
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    
  }
})
```

```css
.app > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  padding-bottom: 4vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.app > ul > li.row > ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
.app > ul > li.row > ul li {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.app > ul > li.row > ul li.selected {
  background-color: gray;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(row, rowIndex) in rows" class="row">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in row.items" :key="index + '_' + rowIndex" :class="{ selected: item.selected }" @click="item.selected = !item.selected"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:** you don't have to hard code those values. You could, if you chose, generate them in a loop on component mounted() (or other suitable event) using `Vue.$set()`.

An example of using `Vue.$set()` in a `mounted()` hook, within your component:

```js
export default {
  mounted () {
    const rows = 8
    const itemsPerRow = 7

    for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
      let row = {
        items: []
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < itemsPerRow; i++) {
        row.items.push({
          selected: false
        })
      }

      this.$set(this.rows, r, row)

    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      rows: []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this works, i want to note that the generated `:key` will not be unique across all items but instead repeat each row. This can be solved by adding an index to the row, multiplying it by the number of items in each row and then adding each individual item index separately. Both, this solution and OP's code have this issue.

Comment: @buffy thanks for pointing this out. Have fixed the issue in my answer.

Comment: Thank you and how exactly should I generate those values using `Vue.$set`? I wouldn't like it to be hardcoded.

Comment: Vue's documentation should help you https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html - but I'll update my answer with an example for you :)